# Grid layoutData is not applied for sap.ui.view elements

Tags: sapui5

Please have a look at the following plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/vsmPEM1Ie8fgAnkSIc4V)

The problem is that when using a view as a template

```
var productTemplate = new sap.ui.view({
      viewName: "view.Product",
      type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS,
      layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({
        span: "L1 M3 S6"
      })
    });
```

the layoutData property object is not applied. The products will be displayed using the Grid defaults "L3 M6 S12" logic.

When using other elements like Label, HTML this bug does not occur.

```
var productTemplate = new sap.ui.commons.Label({
      text: "{name}",
      layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({
        span: "L1 M3 S6"
      })
    });
```

Please have a look in Main.view.js and change the file to test it.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the layoutData is not applied to the view. This happens as the property is not a valid parameter of the [sap.ui.view()](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html#.view) function. Only the following are supported:

- **id** {String}
- **viewName** {String}
- **controller** {sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller}
- **type** {sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType}

The `layoutData` property comes from the [sap.ui.core.Element](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Element.html) which is in the inheritance chain of a view but it´s simply not considered by the sap.ui.view function. However, you can attach it after initialization:

```
var productTemplate = new sap.ui.view({
    viewName: "view.Product",
    type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS
}).setLayoutData(new sap.ui.layout.GridData({
    span: "L1 M3 S6"
}));
```

However, I would not recommend to create a Template for databinding in a separate view since this comes with the whole lifecycle of a view. A better approach would be your second example where you create the Label immediately.